# Display Wordpress child pages on parent page

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to display the content of child pages on a parent page in Wordpress (not posts).  This works, displays the title of the child page, but I can not get the content to display. (last 2 lines)

```
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 1, 'category_name' => 'foundation','post__in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) );

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ($the_query -> have_posts()) {
    $the_query->the_post();
?>

<article class="lead">
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <section>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </section>
</article>

<?php
}

$newQuery = new WP_Query();
$all_pages  = $newQuery->query(array('post_type' => 'page'));

$foundation = get_page_by_title('Foundation');
$foundation_children = get_page_children($foundation->ID, $all_pages);

query_posts('pagename=foundation');

while(have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    the_title();
    the_content();
}

foreach($foundation_children as $tc) {
    echo $tc->post_title; // this works
    echo $tc->the_content; // this doesn't
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct variable is `post_content`.

Try `echo $tc->post_content;`

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post

Comment: Your fix worked for me, thanks but do you know how I can get shortcodes to render in the child pages when displayed on the parent page with post_content?  I have a gallery on the child page, but it's being outputted as plain text on the parent page now.